# Help I got lost in the nether! I need to find my portal to my lux city and I don't have a duplicate!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a really big city in Minecraft, but I carelessly went to the Nether and lost my portal!

I am really far away from it. I have been wandering for days!

I don't have a duplicate of my lux city and I would want to find it because I spent months making the city.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, open the start menu and search "%appdata%" then open ".minecraft". In there will be a folder named "saves" open the folder and find your world folder. Copy the folder... Rename the folder and put it in the "saves" folder. Then when you run minecraft there will be a new singleplayer world named what you called it. It will be the same world as before, but you will be in the overworld at the world spawn.

Comment: Player information is saved in that folder as well, and will be copied along with it, so this won't work.

Comment: If you don't care about the items and achievements just delete them.